# Phpdocumentor namespaces & subpackage

Tags: php, namespaces, package, phpdoc

I currently don't implement namespaces (will probably switch in the future) but I wanted to get the same benefits out of phpdocumentor using @packages and @subpackages.  Otherwise it will just live everything under the default one / and it's messy.

I want to be able to assign some kind of logical ordering,

Root
  libs/
    libs/stuff
    libs/other stuff
  content/
    content/more content
  etc

So it's better organized.  But when I use @package and @subpackage it doesn't do anything, I've tried full pathing everything and playing around with different combinations, regenerating, and clearing my browser cache.  It never changes the organization unless I explicitly use namespaces in my code and it parses it, than it fixes the organization.

I didn't think that was the case when I read the docs on phpdocumentor, I thought it said subpackages was a workaround and not to use both for maintainability (ie if you use namespaces don't use subpacakge tags).

Am I wrong?  Can someone show me a few examples of a working organization using @package and @subpackage?

The reason I'm not using namespaces is because it broke my auto load stuff and I wanted to avoid people having to do I\want\to\contstruct\this\object() for example...so I need to read more up on namespaces, auto loading, and real world applications because I want to make things as simple as possible for people extending the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work as intended, probably a bug.  Maybe it's fixed in a subsequent release.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted so that the StackOverflow community knows you no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

@package and @subpackage should be giving you the results you describe, if your code indeed has no namespaces in it.  If it's not, it is a bug.